# Simple question about a complex valued function

Tags: analysis

This is taken from an exam. One and only one of the answers is true.

Let $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}|f(x)|=+\infty$. Hence:

a)There exists $\varepsilon\in]0,1[$ such that $|f(x)|\geq2\;\;$ if $\;\;|x|\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$;

b)There exists $\varepsilon\in]0,1[$ such that $\cosh(\Re(f(x))+|\Im(f(x))|^4>\varepsilon\;\;$ if $\;\;x\in]\varepsilon,2\varepsilon[$.

If the wrong answer would be the a), then it should be as follows: $\forall\varepsilon\in]0,1[$ there exists $|x|\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\;\;$ s.t $|f(x)|<2\;\;$. But (se my comment below) this contradicts the hypotesis (i.e. $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}|f(x)|=+\infty$). Hence this should be the correct answer.

**BUT** $\cosh(\xi)\geq1\;\;\forall\xi\in\mathbb R$ and the modulus is always $\geq0$, so $\cosh(\Re(f(x))+|\Im(f(x))|^4\geq1\;\;\forall x\in\mathbb R$. Being $\varepsilon\in]0,1[$, is thus clear that $\cosh(\Re(f(x))+|\Im(f(x))|^4>\varepsilon\;\;$ (this holds $\forall x\in\mathbb R$ and then for $x\in]\varepsilon,2\varepsilon[$). It seems that also the b) is true.

I think there is an error, but the teacher doesen't want explain me this.
Please help, thanks.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, why should $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=f(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

Your writing is confusing. First off, the function $f(x)=1/x^2$ for $|x|>0$ and $f(0)=0$ is a perfectly well-defined function whose domain is $\mathbb{R}$ and which satisfies $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} |f(x)|=\infty$. You are mixing up the fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=f(0)$ iff $f$ is continuous.

Second, your negation of (a) is not correct. The correct negation is that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $x$ such that $|x|\leq \epsilon/2$ and $|f(x)|<2$.

Comment: You're right for both. Thanks. But
1)Does the last $f$ you wrote need the absolute value?
2)According to the correct negation of the a), $\forall n\in\mathbb N\;\;\exists x_n$ s.t.$|x_n|\leq\frac{1}{2n}$ s.t. $|f(x_n)|<2$ we would have a sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ s.t. it tends to $0$ and $|f(x_n)|<2\;\;\forall n\in\mathbb N$

Comment: Hence the a) answer can't be wrong.